# Access to libs folder in application package

Tags: android

I added the audio android-ffmeg library project in my application. 
I added a file called libsox.so in the libs folder of the application.

The file is called via a ShellCallback , looking in the file system.
The problem is that it return a "**nullPointerException**", depending on the mobile phone. On my Samsung it works without problem, but this problem appear on other device.
The problem looks to be in the first line:

```
fileBinDir = new File(_context.getFilesDir().getParentFile(),"lib"); 

soxBin = new File(fileBinDir,"libsox.so").getCanonicalPath();
```

Somebody know why it can't be found on some device ?

Answer (score 0):

Native libraries are handled different to assets. Usually you include one library for each platform (armebi, armebi-v7a and x86). When you install the app the matching library in installed and the other libraries are just ignored.

If you want to load a library use `System.loadlibrary("sox")` instead. The "lib" and ".so" parts will be automatically added and Android knows where it installed the library.

Alternatively you can use System.mapLibraryName(..) to get the library file name and then use findLibrary(..) of your current classloader for getting the path to the library.

Comment: Thanks you very much Robert for the clear explanation, it solved my problem.